# How to delete from a text file, all lines that contain a specific string?

Tags: shell, sed, text-parsing, in-place

How would I use sed to delete all lines in a text file that contain a specific string?

Answer (score 3526, accepted):

To remove the line and print the output to standard out:

```
sed '/pattern to match/d' ./infile
```

To directly modify the file – does not work with BSD sed:

```
sed -i '/pattern to match/d' ./infile
```

Same, but for BSD sed (Mac OS X and FreeBSD) – does not work with GNU sed:

```
sed -i '' '/pattern to match/d' ./infile
```

To directly modify the file (and create a backup) – works with BSD and GNU sed:

```
sed -i.bak '/pattern to match/d' ./infile
```

Comment: How do I know what version of sed I have? GNU or non GNU?

Comment: I dont't know why, but the least command resulted in an empty file :(

Comment: With GNU sed 4,2,2, the -i '' doesn't work at all.  It then treats the pattern to match as the filename.  Just remove the ''.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the update. My original answer did not contain the empty quotes part and the answer was edited by the community because of some incompatibility with the OSX version of `sed`.  Hopefully this updated answer will be common for both; it certainly works with GNU `sed` 4.2.2

Comment: on ubuntu `sed -i.bak "/str/d" ./infile` deletes my entire file.

Comment: Note that if your pattern will contain forward slashes, you can use an alternate pattern delimiter but must then escape the first one, e.g.: `sed -i.bak "\#$pattern_variable_containing_slashes#d" ./infile`

Comment: With GNU sed 4.5, the statement `sed -i '/DELETE ME/d' tables.list` just deletes the string "DELETE ME" and leaves the rest of the line there.

Answer (score 725):

There are many other ways to delete lines with specific string besides `sed`:

#### AWK

```
awk '!/pattern/' file > temp && mv temp file
```

#### Ruby (1.9+)

```
ruby -i.bak -ne 'print if not /test/' file
```

#### Perl

```
perl -ni.bak -e "print unless /pattern/" file
```

#### Shell (bash 3.2 and later)

```
while read -r line
do
  [[ ! $line =~ pattern ]] && echo "$line"
done <file > o
mv o file
```

#### GNU grep

```
grep -v "pattern" file > temp && mv temp file
```

And of course `sed` (printing the inverse is faster than actual deletion):

```
sed -n '/pattern/!p' file
```

Comment: how to delete a particular line with a pattern and also the line immediately above it? I have a fine with thousands of such lines in between different data.

Comment: On OS/X, the shell variation doesn't preserve leading spaces, but the grep -v variation worked well for me.

Comment: the `sed` example have a different behaviour, it only greps! it should be something like  `sed -n -i '/pattern/!p' file`.

Comment: The grep version does not work when every line matches the pattern. Better do: `grep -v "pattern" file > temp; mv temp file` This might apply to some of the other examples depending on the return value.

Comment: "printing the inverse is faster than actual deletion" - Not on my machine (2012 MacBook Air, OS X 10.13.2). Create file: `seq -f %f 10000000 >foo.txt`. sed d: `time sed -i '' '/6543210/d' foo.txt` real 0m9.294s. sed !p: `time sed -i '' -n '/6543210/!p' foo.txt` real 0m13.671s. (For smaller files, the difference is larger.)

Comment: would there be any way to leave the first row of the text file, but then apply the delete for all other rows? (for the AWK option) @Peter Mortensen

Comment: @PaulBeusterien If you want to preserve leading and trailing spaces just use `while IFS= read -r line` instead (this behavior has nothing to do with OS/X, this is normal in all POSIX-compliant shells)

Comment: Please explain how `sed -n '/pattern/!p' file` is "faster" than `sed '/pattern/d' file`

Answer (score 335):

You can use sed to replace lines in place in a file. However, it seems to be much slower than using grep for the inverse into a second file and then moving the second file over the original.

e.g.

```
sed -i '/pattern/d' filename
```

or

```
grep -v "pattern" filename > filename2; mv filename2 filename
```

The first command takes 3 times longer on my machine anyway.

Comment: Voting up your answer too, just because you tried a performance comparison!

Comment: +1 for offering option to overwrite current file with the grep line.

Comment: for some reason the mac os sed version(BSD) is not accepting zero-lenght backup file name but when one is provided it works.

Comment: The second 'grep' solution is also better for large files

Comment: I'm curious what the performance difference would be if it were `sed '/pattern/d' filename > filename2; mv filename2 filename`

Comment: (using ubuntu's /usr/share/dict/words) grep and mv: 0.010s | sed in place: 0.197s | sed and mv: 0.031s

Comment: How can I delete the line containing a text in *ANY* file? Lets say I am in /var/www/html/ and want to delete a line containing "hacker.com" in any PHP file?

Comment: find . -type f -name "*.php" | xargs -ifile sed -i '/hacker.com/d' file

Comment: `cat filename | grep -v "pattern" > filename`

Comment: How can I delete lines in a directory that contain a specific string

Answer (score 110):

The easy way to do it, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed --in-place '/some string here/d' yourfile
```

Comment: A handy tip for others who stumble on this Q&A thread and are new to shell scripting: Short options are fine for one-time uses on the command line, but long options should be preferred in scripts since they're more readable.

Comment: +1 for the --in-place flag.  I need to test that out on permissions protected files.  (have to do some user scrubbing.)

Comment: Note that the long option is only available on GNU sed. Mac and BSD users will need to install gsed to do it this way.

Comment: Another tip: if your regex doesn't appear to match, try the `-r` option (or `-E`, depending on your version). This enables the use of regex metacharacters `+`, `?`, `{...}` and `(...)`.

Comment: This is the correct answer when your disk no have more space and you can't copy the text to another file. This command do what was questioned?

Comment: @ferreirabraga no "This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place. GNU sed does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to this file rather than to the standard output."

Answer (score 46):

You may consider using [`ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) (which is a standard Unix command-based editor):

```
ex +g/match/d -cwq file
```

where:

- `+` executes given Ex command (`man ex`), same as `-c` which executes `wq` (write and quit)
- `g/match/d` - Ex command to delete lines with given `match`, see: [Power of g](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g#Examples)

The above example is a POSIX-compliant method for in-place editing a file as per this [post at Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253820/21471) and [POSIX specifications for `ex`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253820/21471).

---

The difference with `sed` is that:

> `sed` is a **S**tream **ED**itor, not a file editor.<sup>[BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021)</sup>

Unless you enjoy unportable code, I/O overhead and some other bad side effects. So basically some parameters (such as in-place/`-i`) are non-standard FreeBSD extensions and may not be available on other operating systems.

Comment: that's great... when I do `man ex` it gives me the man for `vim`, it seems `ex` is part of vim... if I understood right that means the pattern syntax for `match` is http://vimregex.com/ which is similar but different to POSIX and PCRE flavours?

Comment: `:g ` is [POSIX-compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) command with some [slight differences](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253820/21471). I assume PCRE was based on it.

Comment: @kenorb "I/O overhead and some other bad side effects" could you elaborate? AFAIK `ex` is using a temp file, just like every other sane tool, besides idk using `dd`

Answer (score 28):

I was struggling with this on Mac. Plus, I needed to do it using variable replacement.

So I used:

`sed -i '' "/$pattern/d" $file`

where `$file` is the file where deletion is needed and `$pattern` is the pattern to be matched for deletion.

I picked the `''` from this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string-using-sed#comment28307642_5410784).

The thing to note here is use of *double quotes* in `"/$pattern/d"`. Variable won't work when we use single quotes.

Comment: Mac `sed` requires a parameter after `-i`, so if you don't want a backup, you still have to add an empty string: `-i ''`

Comment: For shell use `sed -i "/$pattern/d" $file` . Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 23):

You can also use this:

```
 grep -v 'pattern' filename
```

Here `-v` will print only other than your pattern (that means invert match).

Answer (score 18):

To get a inplace like result with `grep` you can do this:

```
echo "$(grep -v "pattern" filename)" >filename
```

Comment: This is only good for the `bash` shell or similar (not `tcsh`).

Answer (score 17):

Delete lines from all files that match the match

```
grep -rl 'text_to_search' . | xargs sed -i '/text_to_search/d'
```

Answer (score 16):

I have made a small benchmark with a file which contains approximately 345 000 lines. The way with `grep` seems to be around 15 times faster than the `sed` method in this case.

I have tried both with and without the setting LC_ALL=C, it does not seem change the timings significantly. The search string (CDGA_00004.pdbqt.gz.tar) is somewhere in the middle of the file.

Here are the commands and the timings:

```
time sed -i "/CDGA_00004.pdbqt.gz.tar/d" /tmp/input.txt

real    0m0.711s
user    0m0.179s
sys     0m0.530s

time perl -ni -e 'print unless /CDGA_00004.pdbqt.gz.tar/' /tmp/input.txt

real    0m0.105s
user    0m0.088s
sys     0m0.016s

time (grep -v CDGA_00004.pdbqt.gz.tar /tmp/input.txt > /tmp/input.tmp; mv /tmp/input.tmp /tmp/input.txt )

real    0m0.046s
user    0m0.014s
sys     0m0.019s
```

Comment: Which platform are you on? Which versions of sed/perl/grep do you use?

Comment: The platform I use is Linux (Gentoo). The sed version is GNU sed v 4.2.2, the perl version perl 5 (I cant tell which revision I used at the time of the test), and grep (GNU) is version 3.0.

Answer (score 10):

SED:

- [`'/James\|John/d'`](http://sed.js.org/?gist=d9270c2789f1cc82a4898ad5a7297388)
- [`-n '/James\|John/!p'`](http://sed.js.org/?gist=0b78ac2ebeb4dc884083329ab09445ce)

AWK:

- [`'!/James|John/'`](http://awk.js.org/?gist=b2d6c62828b0daf29d7cf9be3c9e34f5)
- [`/James|John/ {next;} {print}`](http://awk.js.org/?gist=b2d6c62828b0daf29d7cf9be3c9e34f5)

GREP:

- [`-v 'James\|John'`](http://grep.js.org/?gist=ba9b48ebf847e88fcf060e00ff45203f)

Answer (score 7):

You can also delete a range of lines in a file.
For example to delete stored procedures in a SQL file.

`sed '/CREATE PROCEDURE.*/,/END ;/d' sqllines.sql`

This will remove all lines between CREATE PROCEDURE and END ;.

I have cleaned up many sql files withe this sed command.

Answer (score 6):

```
perl -i    -nle'/regexp/||print' file1 file2 file3
perl -i.bk -nle'/regexp/||print' file1 file2 file3
```

The first command edits the file(s) inplace (-i).

The second command does the same thing but keeps a copy or backup of the original file(s) by adding .bk to the file names (.bk can be changed to anything).

Answer (score 4):

`echo -e "/thing_to_delete\ndd\033:x\n" | vim file_to_edit.txt`

Answer (score 4):

Curiously enough, the accepted answer does not actually answer the question directly. The question asks about using sed to replace a *string*, but the answer seems to presuppose knowledge of how to convert an arbitrary string into a *regex*.

Many programming language libraries have a function to perform such a transformation, e.g.

```
python: re.escape(STRING)
ruby: Regexp.escape(STRING)
java:  Pattern.quote(STRING)
```

But how to do it on the command line?

Since this is a sed-oriented question, one approach would be to use sed itself:

```
sed 's/\([\[/({.*+^$?]\)/\\\1/g'
```

So given an arbitrary string $STRING we could write something like:

```
re=$(sed 's/\([\[({.*+^$?]\)/\\\1/g' <<< "$STRING")
sed "/$re/d" FILE
```

or as a one-liner:

```
 sed "/$(sed 's/\([\[/({.*+^$?]\)/\\\1/g' <<< "$STRING")/d"
```

with variations as described elsewhere on this page.

Comment: Where's the target file path in the last syntax?

Answer (score 4):

I found most of the answers not useful for me, If you use vim I found this very easy and straightforward:

`:g/<pattern>/d`

[Source](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Delete_all_lines_containing_a_pattern)

Comment: if your comfortable with `vim` as opposed to `sed` you can use `ex` https://stackoverflow.com/a/33186317 beware that it's slower. What's nice about `vim` is you can `\v<pattern>` to avoid backslashitis

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone wants to do it for exact matches of strings, you can use the `-w` flag in grep - w for whole. That is, for example if you want to delete the lines that have number 11, but keep the lines with number 111:

```
-bash-4.1$ head file
1
11
111

-bash-4.1$ grep -v "11" file
1

-bash-4.1$ grep -w -v "11" file
1
111
```

It also works with the `-f` flag if you want to exclude several exact patterns at once. If "blacklist" is a file with several patterns on each line that you want to delete from "file":

```
grep -w -v -f blacklist file
```

Comment: A bit misleading. `-w, --word-regexp  Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches that form whole words.` vs.
`-x, --line-regexp Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.  For a regular expression pattern, this is like parenthesizing the pattern and then surrounding it with ^ and $.`

Answer (score 3):

to show the treated text in console

```
cat filename | sed '/text to remove/d'
```

to save treated text into a file

```
cat filename | sed '/text to remove/d' > newfile
```

to append treated text info an existing file

```
cat filename | sed '/text to remove/d' >> newfile
```

to treat already treated text, in this case remove more lines of what has been removed

```
cat filename | sed '/text to remove/d' | sed '/remove this too/d' | more
```

the `| more` will show text in chunks of one page at a time.

Comment: With -i you can edit the file in place: `sed -i '/text to remove/d'` filename is the same as cat `filename | sed '/text to remove/d'`

Answer (score 2):

```
cat filename | grep -v "pattern" > filename.1
mv filename.1 filename
```

Comment: You're overwriting a file while it's still in use.

Comment: @DavorCubranic fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can use good old `ed` to edit a file in a similar fashion to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33186317/9952196) that uses `ex`. The big difference in this case is that `ed` takes its commands via standard input, not as command line arguments like `ex` can. When using it in a script, the usual way to accomodate this is to use `printf` to pipe commands to it:

```
printf "%s\n" "g/pattern/d" w | ed -s filename
```

or with a heredoc:

```
ed -s filename <<EOF
g/pattern/d
w
EOF
```

Comment: I think this is the first time I've seen the standard editor recommended as a solution.

Comment: how different is sed than ed here, really?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for doing the same operation on multiple file.

```
for file in *.txt; do grep -v "Matching Text" $file > temp_file.txt; mv temp_file.txt $file; done
```