# Unix commands to remove a particular line form all files

Tags: linux, unix

is there any command or a way in unix to remove particular line from all the files.

example :
I have some 300 .c files where the file header has author name. and I need to remove this line from all the files. I am looking to do this in oneshot.

if there is any command or a way please help me on this.

Thanks..

Comment: You can use perl to do this but please *try* something or do a cursory search before asking like this.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you have a pattern to find these `.c` files, you can use some solutions from [Sed - Delete a line containing a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5410757/1983854):

```
find . -type f -name "your_pattern.c" -exec sed -i '/pattern/d' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
find -iname "*.c" -exec sed -i '/author/'d {} \;
```

First find command will find all c files and then sed will delete the author line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i.bak -pne "s/^whatever it is your line to delete$//" files
```

Will create files without your line with extension .bak. Try it on one file and if you are confident enough to overwrite all your files you can do it by:

```
perl -i -pne "s/^whatever it is your line to delete$//" files
```

This will overwrite the original file. Other similar options are:

```
perl -i -ne "print if !/^whatever it is your line to delete$/" files

perl -i -pne "next if /^whatever it is your line to delete$/" files
```

Make sure you define the line from '^' (begining of line) to '$' (end of line) otherwise you might delete similar lines that have a partial match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
grep -lr "<Authorname keyword>" *.c|xargs sed -i '0,/<Authorname>/d'
```

grep - list all the c files in the location with matching keyword '', then sed - delete the 1st line it matches the keyword

Go through the site [sed examples](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/sed-25-examples-to-delete-line-or.html)

for your future references