# remove lines matching more than one pattern using sed

Tags: sed, awk

I'm trying to remove a few lines matching some regex.

```
curl <url> | sed '/\(foo\|bar\|baz\)/d'
```

i don't want any of those lines to show that match foo, bar or baz

it stops on foo

if this is easier with awk, i'm ok with that.

Comment: Do you mean "i don't want any of those lines to show that match foo, bar _and_ baz"?

Comment: your sed works fine in my env (CGYWIN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or with egrep:

```
curl <url> | egrep -v "foo|bar|baz"
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
curl <url> | sed '/foo\|bar\|baz/d'
```

also see many many close examples here: 
http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/sed-25-examples-to-delete-line-or.html

Comment: it actually works as expect. the docs say that it stops at first matching regex. i need to make it greedy, but /g did not work.

Comment: you might find some of the things here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/sed-delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
curl <url> | awk '!/foo|bar|baz/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/foo/{/bar/{/baz/d}}' file
```

or:

```
sed '/foo/!b;/bar/!b;/baz/d' file
```