# insert lines based on a pattern using awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a flat file1 in below format

```
Keyword:
First line

Keyword:
line1 
Line2

Keyword:
abc
def
jkl

Keyword:
123456
opertxt
```

I am using the below awk command and getting the output in file2

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "Keyword:" } {$1=$1} 1' file1 > file2
```

file2 looks like this

```
First line
line1 Line2
abc def jkl
123456 opertxt
```

I do not want to output like this, instead I want the output like the below pattern, the line with the keyword to be removed

```
First line

line1 
Line2

abc
def
jkl

123456
opertxt
```

can someone suggest a solution using awk or sed.
Thanks

Comment: `sed '/keyword:/d' filename`

Comment: A web search for [delete lines matching pattern](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=linux+delete+lines+matching+pattern) gives a __lot__ of results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sed - Delete a line containing a specific string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/sed-delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of these:

```
sed '/^Keyword:$/d' file
```

`sed` looks for lines being exactly `Keyword:` and `d`eletes them.

```
awk '$0 == "Keyword:" {next} 1' file
```

It checks lines that are exactly `Keyword:` and skips them with `next`. Then `1` is True, so it performs the default awk action: `{print $0}`.

Or better and shorter ([thanks Jaypal!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604836/insert-lines-based-on-a-pattern-using-awk/23604980?noredirect=1#comment36258115_23604980)):

```
awk '$0 != "Keyword:"' file
```

#### Output:

```
$ awk '$0 == "Keyword:" {next} 1' file
First line

line1
Line2

abc
def
jkl

123456
opertxt

$ sed '/^Keyword:$/d' file
First line

line1
Line2

abc
def
jkl

123456
opertxt
```

Comment: once i get the output using 
sed '/^Keyword:$/d' file
can is remove blank line using ?
sed '/^\n$/d' file

Comment: Do you also want to remove blank lines? You can use either `sed 's/^$/d' file` or `awk 'NF>=1'`

Comment: yes i wanted to remove all the blank lines. Thanks. I will use the sed command.

Comment: +1 for two solutions. The `awk` can be written as `awk '$0!="Keyword:"' file`

Comment: Oh @jaypal, makes sense and it is even better. Updating, thanks!