# How would I use sed command to delete text within a document?

Tags: unix, sed, terminal

I'm trying to sort and edit a long .txt file and I would like to delete all instances of the following from any line containing it.

```
[getpwnam_ext]
```

Comment: This question has been answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/sed-delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string

Comment: at least, show what you try/search before asking a solution. Stackoverflow is not a code generator but a way to help to solve a problem about code or concept of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to remove just the text you mentioned, use:

```
sed -i 's/\[getpwnam_ext\]//g' filename
```

to remove the whole line that contains that text, use:

```
sed -i '/\[getpwnam_ext\]/d' filename
```

Comment: I get this error

sed: 1: "auth_2014uniq.txt": command a expects \ followed by text

Also, [getpwnam_ext] is part of a word, I guess, which is od[getpwnam_ext], so I'm not sure if that makes a difference