# Using xargs with awk to modify files in-place (on a Mac!)

Tags: macos, awk, find, xargs

I've been trying to delete all lines with the word 'kittens' from a text file on my mac. I've been using find with xargs to do this, but it's not working. Previously I tried using sed with the modify in place option, but to no avail. How can I replace each file using the awk command?

```
gfind -iname "dogs_kittens.txt" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -0 -I %in <awk '!/kittens/{print}' %in > %in
```

Comment: Have you tried passing an empty argument to the -i switch?  It appears to be required on the Mac version of sed.  See one of the comments on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5410784/153430

Comment: change `>%in` to `>tmp && mv tmp %in

Answer (score 2):

I think that something like this would be suitable:

```
awk '!/kittens/' dogs_kittens.txt > tmp && mv tmp dogs_kittens.txt
```

For every line that doesn't match `/kittens/`, perform the default action, which is to print the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to try `sed` again it should be straightforward:

```
gfind -iname "dogs_kittens.txt" -type f -execdir sed -i .meow '/kittens/d' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using the gfind for this, as sed alone should be sufficient:

```
sed -i '' '/kittens/d' dogs_kittens.txt
```

On OS X the in-place place editing requires that you use it with `-i(space)''` to overwrite the input file.

Comment: I would have assumed it was because there were multiple files underneath the directory being searched.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, Yes, although they didn't mention all files, just "from a text file". Also, `gfind` is not native to the OS X version of GNU Utils, at least not that I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a recent version of GNU awk it has a `-i inplace` option for that.