# How to remove a special string from a file?

Tags: sed

Im trying to remove the following two lines:

```
<STREAMINFO> 1 39
<VECSIZE> 39<NULLD><MFCC_D_A_0><DIAGC>
```

which are repeated many times in a texfile (hmmdefs) in the folder hmm0.

How could I do that in UNUX?

Tried to remove each time separately, but when running the following command in command-line:

```
sed "<STREAMINFO> 1 39" hmm0/hmmdefs
```

I receive the following error:

```
sed: 1: "<STREAMINFO> 1 39": invalid command code <
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete a line containing a specific string using sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string-using-sed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `d` flag to delete the line which was matched by the given regex. And don't forget to enclose the regex within the `/` delimiters.

```
sed "/<STREAMINFO> 1 39/d" hmm0/hmmdefs
```

To be more specific, you need to add anchors.

```
sed "/^<STREAMINFO> 1 39$/d" hmm0/hmmdefs
```

`^` Asserts that we are at the start and `$` asserts that we are at the end.

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
<STREAMINFO> 1 39
<VECSIZE> 39<NULLD><MFCC_D_A_0><DIAGC>
foo bar
$ sed '/<STREAMINFO> 1 39\|<VECSIZE> 39<NULLD><MFCC_D_A_0><DIAGC>/d' file
foo bar
```

Comment: I have another question, I tried to post it separately but it says I should wain 90 minutes...  I have a file containing the string `"proto"` which is repeated 384 times.  Each `"proto"` should be edited according to 384 different labels existing in another textfile. For insance, if the content of the second text file is `a, sp, ..` (each label exists in a newline), so in my textfile the first "proto" should be changed to `"a"`, the second to `"sp"` and so on. How should I do that?

Comment: wait and ask it as a new question.