# remove a specific month-day (leapyear day, to be exact. ie: 02-29) from time series

Tags: python, shell, datetime, pandas, awk

I would like to use awk (though open to python/pandas solutions) to pull everything but a specific day form a timeseries dataset. The specific day happens only sometimes throughout the file, as it is a leapyear day that is only present if there were records being taken during a leapyear.

Dataset looks like this, as an example of where a leapyear-day instance occurs:

```
02-28   HammondBay  139 279 30  49.23281860 -123.96769714   4   5150    69.9
02-29   HammondBay  139 279 30  49.23281860 -123.96769714   1   1437    50.9
03-01   HammondBay  139 279 30  49.23281860 -123.96769714   4   5754    59.0
03-02   HammondBay  139 279 30  49.23281860 -123.96769714   4   5732    54.8
03-03   HammondBay  139 279 30  49.23281860 -123.96769714   4   5724    128.5
```

So the intended outcome, just to be clear is a file with every instance of 02-29 removed from this tab-delimited timeseries dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I came upon some removal (or stripping off from) methods at [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string-using-sed)

The solution to the above problem, using awk, is thus:

```
awk '!/02-29/' file > temp && mv temp.whatever file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '!/02-29/' your_file.txt | tee new_file.txt
```

How about `grep`:

```
grep -Ev '02-29' your_file.txt > new_file.txt
```

Comment: ooo good use of grep. I like the inverse matching method. Thank you for the different methods! As an aside, is "tee" basically like using the > command? If so, is one more efficient?

Comment: Thxs. With >  redirect prog output to a file.  With Pipe (|) provide input to a program tee which saves to file and displays on the screen. 'Tee' as in  a 'T junction" - here i split output of the awk to display and save.

Comment: Good explanation. I am about to post another question in a couple minutes that I think you will have a solution for, stay tuned :)

Comment: thank you for the tip. Does the shoe up voting thing go both ways? ;)

Answer (score 1):

To remove all lines that start with `02-29` prefix **inplace**, you could use `sed -i`:

```
$ sed -i '/^02-29/d' input.txt
```

Or using `grep` + `sponge`:

```
$ grep -v '^02-29' input.txt | sponge input.txt
```

where `sponge` utility from `moreutils` allows to overwrite the file that is used in the pipeline as an input.