# find and remove a line in multiple files

Tags: linux, terminal, console

I have many files, and I have to find a single line in these files and delete, and should be in terminal in linux. Anyone know how to do?

Example

FileSystem

```
myFiles
   + file1
   + file2
   ...
   + file6500
```

The file

```
aaa0
aaa1
....
fff9
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? How to do what *exactly*? Remove a single line matching a pattern in every file? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would delete that line in each file.

```
for f in myFiles/*; do
  sed -i 'd/pattern that matches line that you want to delete/' $f
done
```

Alternatively you could use awk as well.

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
for f in myFiles/*; do
  awk '!/pattern that matches the line that you want to delete/' $f > $tmp
  cp $tmp $f 
done
rm $tmp
```

The pattern here would be a regular expression.  You can specify different variants of regular expressions, e.g. **POSIX** or **extended** by passing different flags to sed or awk.  Let me know if this adequately answers your question.

After responding to your question, I found it to be a duplicate: [Delete lines in a text file that containing a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string-using-sed)