# How can i remove "<MAXROWS/>" string from all 30 files in my directory through linux / unix command?

Tags: linux, unix

How can i remove "" string from all 30 files in my directory through linux / unix command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete a line containing a specific string using sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string-using-sed)

Comment: see, I'm new in LINUX so i don't know how to delete it! can you please help me? #GHajba

Comment: Read the answer of the related question I linked in the comment. Then you will see the how to delete the line. Not searching for an answer and asking a question is a very bad habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with sed:

```
sed -i 's/<MAXROWS\/>//g' *
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the old files unmodified you can use this command :
sed -i.backup -e 's/stringtobemodified//g' * && mkdir unmodified && mv *.backup unmodified

if you run that chain command it will modify all files as you wanted and create a new directory named "unmodified" and it will save a copy of each  file with the extension .backup and it will move the backup files to the "unmodified" directory

Comment: That's a good answer -- just be careful of the formatting. Use \`backticks\` around commands not just for a nicer look, but also to escape the Markdown/HTML meaning of characters inside your command. Right now it looks like you're suggesting the sed script 's///g' which I'm sure is not what you mean!