# Delete lines by pattern in specific range of lines

Tags: sed

I want to remove lines from file by regex pattern using `sed` just like in this question [Delete lines in a text file that containing a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5410757/7217), but only inside a range of lines (not in the whole file). I want to do it starting from some line number till the end of file.

This is how I've done it in combination with `tail`:

- `tail -n +731 file|sed '/some_pattern/d' >> file`
- manually remove edited range in `file` from previous step

Is there a shorter way to do it with `sed` only?
Something like `sed -i '731,1000/some_pattern/d' file`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed -i.bak '731,1000{/some_pattern/d}' yourfile
```

**Test:**

```
$ cat a
1
2
3
13
23
4
5

$ sed '2,4{/3/d}' a
1
2
23
4
5
```

Answer (score 5):

You need `$` address to match end of file. With GNU sed:

```
sed -i '731,${/some_pattern/d;}' file
```

Note that this can be slower than `tail -n +number`, because `sed` will start processing at start of file instead of doing [lseek()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lseek.html#) like `tail`.

(With BSD sed you need `sed -i '' ...`)

Comment: This doesn't work, at least with GNU sed 4.2.2: `sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown command: '/'`.

Comment: @ks1322: Sorry, my bad, missing curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything even marginally more interesting an awk solution will be clearer, more robust, portable, maintainable, extensible and better in just about ever other desirable attribute of software.

Given this sample input file:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

The following script will print every line except a line containing the number `3` that occurs after the 6th line of the input file:

```
$ awk '!(NR>6 && /3/)' file
1
2
3
4
1
2
4
1
2
4
```

Want to only do the deletion between lines 6 and 10? No problem:

```
$ awk '!(NR>6 && NR<10 && /3/)' file
1
2
3
4
1
2
4
1
2
3
4
```

Want the skipped lines written to a log file? No problem:

```
awk 'NR>6 && /3/{print > "log";next} {print}' file
```

Written to stderr?

```
awk 'NR>6 && /3/{print | "cat>&2";next} {print}' file
```

Want a count of how many lines you deleted also written to stderr?

```
awk 'NR>6 && /3/{print | "cat>&2"; cnt++; next} {print} END{print cnt | "cat>&2"}' file
```

ANYTHING you want to do additionally or differently will be easy and build on what you start with. Try doing any of the above, or just about anything else, with a sed script that satisfies your original requirement.

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue!

```
awk '!(NR>=731 && /pattern/)' input > output
```