# How sed exact match from url strings in input file and remove it?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a input / input file containing lines with urls like this

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXw6OdVmMpw          Mon Nov 2 10:25:32 2015 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXw6OdVmMpw          Mon Nov 2 10:27:34 2015
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXw6OdVmMpw          Mon Nov 2 10:28:23 2015
```

I want grep only they exact matched string like if i sed for the last line 
which is  `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXw6OdVmMpw          Mon Nov 2 10:28:23 2015`

so it will delete the last line only 
Note : Lines may contain same text at front but different date and time so i need exact match ,
thanks for understanding .

Comment: why dont you just `grep` it? if you dont want that line do `grep -v`

Comment: wait let me check it :) thanks for the quick response .

Comment: grep -v working fine how can i replace the input file content with output content at place ??

Comment: sorry i didnt get  it ? give example what you want to achive ? you want to replace the grep'ed line with something else ?

Comment: am greping the url line from input file say file.txt and i want write the output to same file file.txt

Comment: like in sed we do sed -i  <string to sed> fileinput.txt >fileinput.txt to replace the content of inpput file with the output of sed

Comment: `cat file.txt | grep -v 'what_you_dont_want' >> file.txt`, but this will keep orignal file same and append output to file, if you wan to remove the content do `cat file.txt | grep -v 'what_you_dont_want' > file1.txt && mv file1.txt file.txt`

Comment: no no i want to replace the content at place (input file) we can do that using sed but i dont know how do it with grep .

Comment: yeah using mv command can do the trick :)

Comment: with which string you want to replace ?

Comment: will you please answer the question instead of commenting , i think it is solved , grep cant do inplace replacing .

Comment: @AmeyJadiye: `cat file | grep something` is [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). Try to avoid it...

Comment: yeah , its useless here

Comment: can you please correct the question, its unclear whats input and whats output you want? so lot of questions are coming in mind.

Comment: Regardless of what your problem is, this is probably a duplicate.  Have a look at the highest-voted [tag:sed] questions and look for something suitable.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string-using-sed

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to use the url at the beginning of line replace the whole line?
Two parts of regex in the command below:
1. Match the URL:

> ^([a-zA-Z0-9:/.?=]*)

2. Match the last part:

> .*

Then use the URL part replace the whole line.

```
echo "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXw6OdVmMpw          Mon Nov 2 10:28:23 2015" | sed 's/^\([a-zA-Z0-9:/.?=]*\).*/\1/'
```

the result is

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXw6OdVmMpw
```

Is this what you want?

[image]

Comment: With standard `echo` the result is not what you show.  It's not clear how you expect this to solve the OP's question anyway (though the question is also so unclear that this might actually be a possible interpretation, although I don't see how to reach it).

Comment: @tripleee I thought he want to use the url at the beginning of line replace the whole line.

Comment: @tripleee I think I am using the standard bash and echo. No alias on echo. Bash version GNU bash  4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

Answer (score -2):

required output can be achieved by using:

```
grep -v 'text to grep'
```