# Rewriting git history, rewrite addition and removal commits

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a local branch in which I did some development, the commit history is pretty bad so I am going back and rebasing to tidy up and leave it in a sensible state before pushing.

Say I have commits A, B, C, D, E. In commit B I have added some useful code that I want to keep but I also added some debug code. I then later removed the debug code in D. What is the best approach to use to remove this entirely from the history (the code isn't of any use so I don't want it in the history if possible)?

I have tried rebasing at A, rewriting the commit at B without the code but then C and D need manual intervention at each rebase step.
Is it best to split B,D into B-keep and B-remove and D-keep and D-remove then remove the two commits? Is there other ways to clean up when code has been added then removed?

I want to end up with history that looks like A, B(useful), C, D(useful), E which I then may squash to A, B, E for example, at this stage I just want to remove the debug code from the history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If commit `D` it is just removing debug code from commit B then you can reorder commits and squash using `rebase -i`, for example, when you starting rebasing you will see here:

```
pick c9a8ee8 B
pick f533903 C
pick c66cc92 D
pick 647ab90 E
```

Now you need to move commit `D` after commit `B`, you just need to edit text content:

```
pick c9a8ee8 B
pick c66cc92 D
pick f533903 C
pick 647ab90 E
```

And finally you need to change `pick` to `squash` for commit `D`, here is how it will looks:

```
pick c9a8ee8 B
squash c66cc92 D
pick f533903 C
pick 647ab90 E
```

After finishing rebasing, commit `D` will be part of commit `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Applying to your Q update:

You can use this tool to loop over the commits and remove the unwanted commits.
https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Read the example section on how to use it.

It's much faster than `git filter-branch` but has the same effect.

---

Some other options:

Read here in details about each options:
[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revet-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716)

#### `git rebase -i`

Edit each commit you want to clean and remove your code from it. It's useful if you don't have too many commits, if you do - use the `filter-branch` or 'bfg-repo-cleaner'

#### `git checkout`

```
git checkout <commit_id>
```

---

#### `git reflog`

You can always use the `reflog` as well

```
git reflog
git checkout HEAD@{...}
```

This will get you back to your desired commit

---

#### `git reset HEAD --hard <commit_id>`

"Move" your head back to the desired commit.

```sh
# This will destroy any local modifications.
# Don't do it if you have uncommitted work you want to keep.
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32

# Alternatively, if there's work to keep:
git stash
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32
git stash pop
# This saves the modifications, then reapplies that patch after resetting.
# You could get merge conflicts, if you've modified things which were
# changed since the commit you reset to.
```

- Note: ([Since Git 2.7](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.7.0.txt))
  you can also use the `git rebase --no-autostash` as well.

---

#### `git checkout`

```
git checkout -b <new branch> <commit_id>
git checkout HEAD~X // x is the number of commits t go back
```

This will checkout new branch pointing to the desired commit

Comment: I've added a little to the end of the question but I don't see how the above gets me where I want to be.

Answer (score 0):

The usual fix is using [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), combine with [`sed`, to delete line matching a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5410784/6309):

```
# find out the desired file and execute sed on it to find out
# where is the debug code inside the file
git filter-branch --tree-filter "find . -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/pattern with debug/d' {} \;" -- A~..
```

You can refine the find criteria, to find only files with a certain extension (`--name '*.java'`)

That will remove the debug code from history, without needing manual intervention for intermediate commits.
Of course, that will rewrite the SHA1 for all concerned commits, forcing you to do a `git push --force`, so if you are not alone working one that repo, do communicate the impending reset of your branch to the other collaborators.

Comment: This assumes that the "debug code" can be easily detected through a pattern. If the debug code is complex/over multiple lines, that won't be as easy.

Comment: In this case (complex code or few patterns) its better to use squash.