# how to delete a line from a file matching a particular pattern

Tags: sed

I have a file **raw-vobs-config-spec** which has these lines,

```
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/opensso_policy_agt/tomcat-v6/3_0-ER2/... VERSION_04
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/opensso/8_0_build6/... VERSION_01
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_beanutils/1_8_2/... TPLBASE
#element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_collections/3_2_2/... TPLBASE
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_collections/3_2_2/... /main/LATEST
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_collections/3_2_2/... /CHECKEDOUT
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_digester/1_8_1/... TPLBASE
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_el/1_0/... TPLBASE
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_jexl/2_0/... TPLBASE
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_scxml/0_9/... TPLBASE
```

How can I delete the lines?

```
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_collections/3_2_2/... /main/LATEST
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_collections/3_2_2/... /CHECKEDOUT
```

and uncomment this line

```
#element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_collections/3_2_2/... TPLBASE
```

I tried,

```
sed -i '/patter/d' filename
```

but it is not working.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5410757/3365426

Answer (score 0):

One fast way to delete lines from a file is to use the `-n` option in conjunction with a negated pattern:

> Print lines that do not match the pattern

```
sed -n '/pattern/!p'
```

For example:

```
$ cat foo
foo
bar
baz
$ sed -n '/^b/!p' foo
foo
```

As for uncommenting, just drop a leading `#` (after Ed Morton's suggestion):

```
sed 's/^#//'
```

Example with the above file:

```
$ sed 's/^b//' foo
foo
ar
az
```

Comment: @EdMorton Of course! Thank you very much for the pointer. (I am myself still learning, as you can see)