# Remove newlines (\n) if they are followed by a string - using SED

Tags: regex, awk, replace, sed

I have a text file and I need to remove newlines if they are followed by the string "fox"

```
the 
brown 
fox 
jumps
```

will become

```
the 
brown fox 
jumps
```

I would like to do it in SED, but the AWK solution would be useful too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete a line containing a specific string using sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string-using-sed)

Comment: I think it's quite a distinct question. This is for deleting newlines (\n), not entire lines. And the decision is based on the content of the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/\nfox/s/\n//;ta;P;D' file
```

Read two lines into the pattern space and if the second line matches the criteria, remove the newline and repeat. The first line is always printed and then deleted. If the pattern space still has a line in it i.e. the criteria was not matched, another line is appended etc however if the line did meet the criteria the pattern space is empty and two lines will be read in as they would be such as at the beginning of the file.

Comment: It works but not when having consecutive lines containing the string. Try doubling the line containing "fox" and it will only delete the first newline that it's supposed to delete

Comment: `;P;D` can be removed - the result, as far as I can see, is identical. check it out: `sed ':a;N;/\nfox/s/\n//;ta' file`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin see comment above

Answer (score 3):

With Perl:

```
perl -0pe 's/\nfox/fox/g' file
```

Output:

```
the 
brown fox 
jumps
```

Comment: I think you have to use a back-slash to escape that slash which is in your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a job for sed, it is a job for awk:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{printf "%s", (/fox/ ? OFS : ORS)} {printf "%s", $0} END{print ""}' file
the
brown fox
jumps
```

The above replaces the newline (ORS) before fox with a blank char (OFS). Massage to suit...

With GNU awk you can alternatively reduce it to:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{gsub(/\nfox/," fox")} 1' file
the
brown fox
jumps
```

or:

```
$ awk -v RS='\nfox' '{ORS=gensub(/\n/," ",1,RT)} 1' file
the
brown fox
jumps
```

but that reads the whole file into memory at one time.