# Remove lines with specific pattern with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a file with one word/character for each line. Example:

```
a
abandonado
esta
estabelecimento
o
onibus
c
casa
police
```

I need remove lines with specific pattern (ex. pattern "esta"). I tried with awk

```
cat file | awk '!/^esta/'
```

but this solution remove the all lines with  the pattern `"esta"` and `"estabelecimento"` too. I need only remove the line with the specific pattern `"esta"` not line with `"estabelecimento"`.

The same problem occurs with the lines with the patterns `"o"` and `"a"`. The command removes all lines with start with this pattern.

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

simple using `grep`:

```
grep -v -w esta file
```

- `-w` option matches "word only" / "exact word": exactly what you need
- `-v` option reverses matches: only prints the lines which don't match

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this with `sed` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-lines-in-a-text-file-that-containing-a-specific-string) question:

```
$ cat test.txt
a
abandonado
esta
estabelecimento
o
onibus
c
casa
police
```

.

```
$ sed '/^esta$/d' test.txt
a
abandonado
estabelecimento
o
onibus
c
casa
police
```

`grep` is simpler but `sed` can give you more flexibility, depends on your use case & comfort level with each.

Comment: There is no need to use cat, sed itself is capable to read the file and do the operations, it is often called UUOC(Useless use of cat).

Answer (score 4):

Your idea is right, `^` matches the start of pattern, finish it by matching `$` for pattern end, so that the whole-word is matched as it is

```
awk '!/^esta$/' file
a
bandonado
estabelecimento
o
onibus
c
casa
police
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your file consists of lines with just one column you can check if a column matches a string.

This removes the need for anchors `^`, `$`:

```
$ awk '$1 != "esta" {print}' file
  a
  abandonado
  estabelecimento
  o
  onibus
  c
  casa
  police
```