# How to delete lines from a file that start with certain words

Tags: unix, sed, grep

My file extension is CSV file looks below format in unix server.

> "Product_Package_Map_10302017.csv","451","2017-10-30 05:02:26"
>   "Targeting_10302017.csv","13","2017-10-30 05:02:26",
>   "Targeting_Options_10302017.csv","42","2017-10-30 05:02:27"

I want to delete a particular line based on filename keyword.

Comment: What do you mean by "filename keyword"?  What have you tried?

Comment: I mean "Product_Package_Map_10302017.csv"" and ITargeting_10302017.csv" like wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep -v`:

```
grep -v '^"Product_Package_Map_10302017.csv"' file > file.filtered
```

- `'^"Product_Package_Map_10302017.csv"'` matches the string `"Product_Package_Map_10302017.csv"` exactly at the line beginning

or `sed` can do it in-place:

```
sed -i '/^"Product_Package_Map_10302017.csv"/d' file
```

---

See this related post for other alternatives:

- [Delete lines in a text file that contain a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-lines-in-a-text-file-that-contain-a-specific-string)

Comment: Is this possible to remove particular line in same file. Instead of creating new file ?

Answer (score 0):

See this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-lines-in-a-text-file-that-contain-a-specific-string). A grep-based answer would be my first choice but, as you can see, there are many ways to address this one!

(Would have just commented, but my 'rep' is not yet high enough)