# Delete a string from line starting with a specific string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file :

```
# Allow incoming TCP ports
TCP_IN = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,4433,465,587,993,995,3306,9200,8080,8888,10000:20000,"

# Allow outgoing TCP ports
TCP_OUT = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,113,143,443,465,4433,587,993,995,3306,9200,8080,8888,10000:20000,"

# Allow incoming UDP ports
UDP_IN = "20,21,53,111"

# Allow outgoing UDP ports
# To allow outgoing traceroute add 33434:33523 to this list 
UDP_OUT = "20,21,53,113,123,111"

# Allow incoming PING. Disabling PING will likely break external uptime
# monitoring
ICMP_IN = "1"
```

I want to delete, lets say `443` from line starting with `TCP_OUT = "` but not from anywhere else in the file.

a `sed` or `awk` solution would be what I am looking for.

Clarification :
I don't want to delete the entire line that starts with a specific string, I want to delete a sub string in a line that starts with a string. ex : I want to delete just the `443` in line that starts with `TCP_OUT = "` I don't want to delete entire line that starts with `TCP_OUT = "`

Comment: maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374127/sed-delete-the-line-start-with-but-not-with-shell-scripts) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-lines-in-a-text-file-that-contain-a-specific-string) can help.

Comment: @TomBombadil those are not want I want, I added some clarification

Comment: Yes I thought you might be able to combine the various information to what you want. I'm sry if it does not help.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed '/^TCP_OUT/ s/443,*//' file
```

Comment: nothing changed in original file.

Comment: If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Comment: It may not work if input is `TCP_OUT = "123,443"`

Answer (score 0):

Use an "address" in sed to run a substitution only on a particular line:

```
sed '/^TCP_IN /s/\([",]\)443[",]/\1/'
```

The `[",]` are needed to correctly handle the cases when 443 is the first or last item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `sed` command:

```
sed -iE '/^TCP_OUT /s/"443"/""/; s/([",])443,|,443([,"])/\1\2/' file
```

This `sed` checks for all of the 4 possible cases:

- When `443` is the only number in input i.e. `"443"`
- When `443` is at the start i.e. `"443,111,222,333"`
- When `443` is at the end i.e. `"987,546,443"`
- When `443` is in the middle i.e. `"111,222,333,443,678,123,098"`

Comment: getting this error : sed: -e expression #1, char 53: invalid reference \2 on 's' command's RHS

Comment: Try this command: `sed -ir '/^TCP_OUT /s/"443"/""/; s/([",])443,|,443([,"])/\1\2/' file`