# eliminate rows from bed file

Tags: shell, file, bioinformatics

I produced a bed file like this

```
Simple_repeat   KQ420259.1  45090   45150   (TTAT)n .   +
Simple_repeat   KQ420259.1  46815   46864   (TG)n   .   +
Simple_repeat   KQ420259.1  47062   47104   (GT)n   .   +
SINE/tRNA-Deu   KQ420259.1  49227   49290   AmnSINE2    .   +
Simple_repeat   KQ416943.1  112522  112609  (ATAC)n .   +
Simple_repeat   KQ416943.1  113250  113283  (ACA)n  .   +
Simple_repeat   KQ416943.1  113283  113358  (ACT)n  .   +
Simple_repeat   KQ416943.1  117308  117357  (AC)n   .   +
Simple_repeat   KQ416943.1  117357  117435  (ACAC)n .   +
Simple_repeat   KQ416944.1  117964  118025  (TATG)n .   +
DNA/TcMar       KQ416944.1  121083  121651  HSMAR1  .   +
Low_complexity  KQ416944.1  124929  124970  A-rich  .   +
```

and I would to eliminate all the rows containing `KQ416943.1` . I don't know if exists a way to do it preserving the order. I'll appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: 1) it's not a BED file. 2) search for `grep`

Comment: why not? there are names, positions, strand. I think it is

Comment: the 3 first columns of a BED file are: CHROM/START/END : https://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat.html#format1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete lines in a text file that contain a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-lines-in-a-text-file-that-contain-a-specific-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
grep -v "KQ416943.1" yourfile.txt > output.txt
```