# How can I exclude lines containing a match found with Ripgrep?

Tags: bash, ag, ripgrep

I am using [`rg`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) (or alternatively [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)) to search for occurrences of a string in a folder with many files, like this:

```sh
$ rg "cat"
lolo
3:cat

lala
2:cat
```

Now I would like to get rid of these matches.

How can I remove each line containing a match from every file with matches?

Comment: I wouldn't use `rg` for this in the first place. Write a small script which is given a file, and if this contains such a line in question, replaces the file by a new one with those lines deleted. Then use `find` to traverse your file tree and apply you script to each file.

Comment: This is job for `awk` or `sed`, our venerated text-processing tools! See <https://stackoverflow.com/a/5410784/8133920>

Answer (score 3):

its `rg -v 'pattern'`.
Same as that of grep

Answer (score 0):

Use `-v` argument, as example:

```
rg -v "cat" test.log
```

Result

```
1:lolo
3:
4:lala
```