# Find and delete entire line in Geany

Tags: regex, geany

I need to obtain something like the following:

```
may 09 00:11:53 USER audit[1225]: Found device /dasd/cxvxc/...
may 09 00:11:53 USER audit[1226]: more text here
may 09 00:11:53 USER audit[1225]: Found device /mnt/cxvxc/...
may 09 00:11:53 USER audit[1225]: FOUND DEVICE /mnt/cxvxc/...
```

And remove all the rows where it finds the occurrence of `found device` (case insensitive).

I tried with `\Found\ device`, but it is not case insensitive and how do I remove the entire line after finding?

Comment: `^.*found device.*$` with no case sensitive, works here.

Comment: Closing this as a [duplicate] makes no sense since the question it links to is about Notepad++ and not Geany. Even if the answer were the same for both, there's no reason to expect that it would stay that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe not the most advanced version, but should do the trick:

Go to Search -> Replace and activate Regular Expressions. Something like this would match your search

```
^.*(Found device|FOUND DEVICE).*$
```

Replace it with an empty string.

[image]

This might leaves empty lines, which you can clean with another round of search and replace by deactivating Regular expressions again and using `\n` for the search-string.

[image]

However, I would recommend you to check more specialized tools like sed or awk --- This answer [Delete lines in a text file that contain a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-lines-in-a-text-file-that-contain-a-specific-string) looks helpful -- and via Geany's "Send selection to"-feature it can be even integrated into Geany quiet easy.