# How do I delete rows from a text file in R?

Tags: python, r

I have a text file with data line items that looks like:

1. 1~123~JJJ
2. 2~223~AAA
3. 3~444~LLL
4. 4~567~PPP
5. 5~785~QQQ

I'd like to delete the lines that contain the following values:(I have another text file that has these values that need to be deleted)
PPP
QQQ

To end up with:

1. 1~123~JJJ
2. 2~223~AAA
3. 3~444~LLL

I have never used R and would like to know if there is a way to have this done. If it can be done in a faster way in Python, please let me know. I am open to options.

Comment: While it could be done - e.g. `readLines()` the data in, identify/remove the rows, `writeLines()` it out again - i'd have to think that using old unix text tools like sed/grep would be more appropriate - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/how-to-delete-from-a-text-file-all-lines-that-contain-a-specific-string

Comment: Per @thelatemail's suggestion, `sed -ibak -e "/(PPP|QQQ)/d" myfile.txt` will delete any line that contains those two strings. And with larger files, it will be faster than R and python ... but I applaud you trying to figure out how to do it in other languages.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a combination of `readLines` and `grepl`, followed by `writeLines`:

```
conn <- file("path/to/input.txt")
lines <- readLines(conn)
close(conn)
lines <- lines[grepl("^(?!.*\\b(?:PPP|QQQ)\\b).*$", lines, perl=TRUE)]

conn <- file("path/to/input.txt", "w")  # assuming you want to write to the same file
writeLines(lines, conn)
close(conn)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` for integer indexing

```
> df[-grep("PPP|QQQ", df$V1), , drop=FALSE]
         V1
1 1~123~JJJ
2 2~223~AAA
3 3~444~LLL
```

Where  `df` is a data.frame:

```
df <- read.table(text="1~123~JJJ
2~223~AAA
3~444~LLL
4~567~PPP
5~785~QQQ", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with R, but here's how I'd do it in python

```
with open("yourfile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("yourfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.__contains__("string to delete"):
            f.write(line)
```

EDIT:
for this to work with reading another file with all of the strings to exclude, you'd do the following:

```
with open("to be deleted.txt", "r") as f:
    parts = f.readlines()
with open("yourfile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("yourfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        for part in parts:
            if not part in line:
                f.write(line)
```

Comment: Is this the full script required ? I am not so great at using python. 

I am guessing after I run it, it becomes a print statement where I enter each item that needs to be removed ?

Comment: should use `in`, not `__contains__`

Comment: @Ggplot see updated answer. This will read all the parts from another file and check if the line contains any of them.