# Removing text and saving files using sed

Tags: sed

I searched here and found I could use sed to edit some text files. These are emlx files from Apple's Mail.app which has added some plist date. I want to remove the line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and all following from the files and save the file.

This (almost) does what I want

```
sed -n '/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>/q;p myfile.emlx
```

Using a Mac, in Terminal I see the file written out having the lines edited out. Good. But I'm soft and don't know how to get sed to save the file. I'm happy to save to the original (I'm working from copies).

Apparently

```
-i
```

should do what I need. But it isn't. Please give me a clue! Then later I'll ask how to deal with a batch of 1500 files.

Comment: For macOs sed use: `sed -i '' '/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>/d' myfile.emlx`

Comment: Check the third code-block [on the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5410784/5625547)

Comment: Yes, I just read about the code I need on macOS so that's working, thanks.

However what that code does is leave my file with the first line I wanted to delete (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>). Although this would work for my needs I expected the saved file to have had that line removed.