# How to delete text/word or character from a text file?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I've seen an interesting [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/how-to-delete-from-a-text-file-all-lines-that-contain-a-specific-string), mine is just the opposite.

I have a text file containing the following:

```
‍ ?Hadoop functions and tutorial?
https://abc. com/id=abc?33m?
 ? java function tutorial
https://abc .com/id=?bc?33m?
```

I've text file content below:

```
‍ ?Hadoop functions ?and tutorial
https://abc. com/id=abc?33m?
 ? java function tutorial
https://abc. com/id=?bc?33m?
```

I want to delete all the questions marks but they should not be removed from the lines containing https/http/HTTPS/HTTP.

I used following script below:

```
cat fi.txt |grep ^?|sed 's#?##g' >title.txt;cat fi.txt|grep ^https >url.txt;paste title.txt url.txt
```

Please help with opposite match function in `sed` or Awk (delete ? text but not from lines which contain https).

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. May I suggest that you take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)?

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed -E '/https?/I!s/\?//g' file`. With another sed: `sed -E '/(https?|HTTPS?)/!s/\?//g' file`.

Comment: I tried to clean up the formatting but this is still quite messy; please review.