# Get rid of message and newline from traceroute using sed/awk

Tags: awk, sed, traceroute

Looking for option to get rid of `traceroute: wrote 0 40 chars, ret=-1` message in its output.
So the output would look just like this:

```
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
```

Best I could achieve is these:

```
$ traceroute -anm 10 -w 1 0 2>/dev/null | sed 's/traceroute:.*/ /'
 1
 *
 *
 *
 2
 *
 *
 *
```

and

```
$ traceroute -anm 10 -w 1 0 2>/dev/null | sed -e 'N;s/traceroute:.*\n/ /'
 1   *traceroute: wrote 0 40 chars, ret=-1
 *  *
 2   *traceroute: wrote 0 40 chars, ret=-1
 *  *
```

Comment: Try pipe your output to `| grep -v traceroute`.

Comment: See: [How to delete from a text file, all lines that contain a specific string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5410757/3776858)

Comment: To delete lines with sed, use the **d** command, as `sed '/traceroute:/d'`.

Comment: Thank you all, but none of those answers my question in part of newline handling

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are happy with how it starts out, you can reassemble the results like this. I am not claiming this is a good design, but if you are still trying, I think it should work, and it keeps the code structure you already had:

```
 $ traceroute -anm 10 -w 1 0 2>/dev/null |  sed 's/traceroute:.*/ /' |\
 awk '/[0-9]/ {printf ("\n%s ", $0)} /*/ {printf("%s ", $0)} END {printf ("\n")}'
```

Which basically says if it is a star, just print it and a spacer, if it is number, print a line feed (to start a new record) and then print the number. At the end, it prints an extra line feed, in case you were in the middle.

It should work fine with multi-digit line numbers as well.

I think I'd probably have tried the whole thing in awk, but if it gets the job done and it is not a production thing, seems this should suffice.