# Delete a row when the first column contains a value equal to zero

Tags: unix, awk

I have a datafile with 5 columns and N numbers of rows, I want delete every rows that have value equal to zero (0.00) in the first column. For example, this is the original file

```
-1.3  -2.00  -3.00  4.00  9.00 
0.10  -0.20  -0.80  4.50  1.70
0.00  -3.40  -6.80  5.60  9.30
-0.4  -3.20  -4.70  0.80  -0.9
1.03  -2.00  -3.00  4.00  9.00 
0.00  -6.80  -9.30  3.40  5.60
0.00  -4.70  -0.80  8.90  -0.3
```

And this is the file that i want to get

```
-1.3  -2.00  -3.00  4.00  9.00 
0.10  -0.20  -0.80  4.50  1.70
-0.4  -3.20  -4.70  0.80  -0.9
1.03  -2.00  -3.00  4.00  9.00
```

Please help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/how-to-delete-from-a-text-file-all-lines-that-contain-a-specific-string

Answer (score 1):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
-1.3  -2.00  -3.00  4.00  9.00 
0.10  -0.20  -0.80  4.50  1.70
0.00  -3.40  -6.80  5.60  9.30
-0.4  -3.20  -4.70  0.80  -0.9
1.03  -2.00  -3.00  4.00  9.00 
0.00  -6.80  -9.30  3.40  5.60
0.00  -4.70  -0.80  8.90  -0.3
```

then

```
awk '!($1=="0.00")' file.txt
```

gives output

```
-1.3  -2.00  -3.00  4.00  9.00 
0.10  -0.20  -0.80  4.50  1.70
-0.4  -3.20  -4.70  0.80  -0.9
1.03  -2.00  -3.00  4.00  9.00
```

Explanation: single condition just describe lines which you want: not (`!`) first field (`$1`) is (`==`) string `0.00` (`"0.00"`)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*