# Remove and add specific key value pair using bash script into Kubernetes YAML

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I want to add and remove specific key value pair into kubernetes yamls

For eg:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: null
    version: latest
  name: null
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: null
      version: latest
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: null
        version: latest
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: aude-service
        name: aude-api
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3003
          hostPort: 3003
          protocol: TCP
```

Contents to be removed in spec after selector:

```
hostPort: 3003
protocol: TCP
```

Contents to be added:

```
strategy:
  type: RollingUpdate 
  rollingUpdate:
    maxUnavailable: 25%
```

It would be of great help, if anyone suggest solution

So, I tried using bash to remove hostport key but it didn't work

```
awk '/^[[:alpha:]]+:/ {level1=$0; next} level1 ~ "hostPort" && /aaa/ {next} 1' aude-convert.yml
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/how-to-delete-from-a-text-file-all-lines-that-contain-a-specific-string

Comment: See: [Is it possible to modify a yml file via shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/338781)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have saved this yaml in `deployment.yaml`.

1. To delete your given content from the yaml.

   ```bash
   sed -i '/hostPort/,/protocol/d' deployment.yaml
   ```

   Here, `/hostPort/,/protocol/` is the range pattern that specifies the lines we want to delete between the pattern `hostPort` and `protocol` (inclusive). `d` is for deleting the lines.
2. To add your given content to the yaml.

   ```bash
   sed -i '/replicas/a \  strategy:\n    type: RollingUpdate\n    rollingUpdate:\n      maxUnavailable: 25%' deployment.yaml
   ```

   Here, `/replicas/a` is the pattern after which we want to append the content. `a` command is for appending content after the given pattern.

   Take care of the spaces here as they should have a proper indentation. Here I have considered 1 tab = 2 spaces. Please modify them according to your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna try something different, you could work with `yq` to achieve the same. `yq` is a lightweight and portable command-line YAML processor. `yq` uses `jq` like syntax but works with yaml files as well as json. Read more about it [here](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/)

So, in your case

To **remove the content** from the yaml:

```
yq -i 'del(.spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports[0].hostPort) | del(.spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports[0].protocol)' deployment.yaml
```

Here we are removing the `hostPort` and `protocol` entries from the first element of the `ports` array.

This gives you a lot of flexibility, for eg if you have multiple `containerPort` & `hostPort` entries you could easily select the second element of the `ports` array:

```
yq -i 'del(.spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports[1].hostPort) | del(.spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports[1].protocol)' deployment.yaml
```

or both elements:

```
yq -i 'del(.spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports[].hostPort) | del(.spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports[].protocol)' deployment.yaml
```

and the same can be applied to `containers[0]` - not providing examples for this but I hope you got the point. Really flexible.

---

To **add the required content** to the yaml:

```
yq -i '.spec.strategy = {"type": "RollingUpdate", "rollingUpdate": {"maxUnavailable": "25%"}}' deployment3.yaml
```

This adds the required content at the end of the file within `spec` (as is defined using `.spec.strategy` in the `cmd`).

To add it right below `replicas`:

```
yq -i '.spec |= {"replicas": .replicas, "strategy": {"type": "RollingUpdate", "rollingUpdate": {"maxUnavailable": "25%"}}, "selector": .selector, "template": .template}' deployment.yaml
```

adding the new `strategy` key-value pair to the `.spec` object along with the existing `.replicas`, `.selector` & `template` key.

This helps with not worrying about spaces or tabs that would come with `sed`.

Hope it helps.