# Remove all characters in all js files after a certain pattern

Tags: linux

I need to remove the content from all js files in a folder (and subfolders) after a certain pattern is detected.

I've tried this using

```bash
find . -type f -name '\*.js' -exec sed -i "s/**PATTERN**.*//" {} \;
```

however this only removes the content of the line that included the `**PATTERN**`

Example:

ORIGINAL FILE

```
aasdja
asdasd PATTERN ajkhsdasjd
akjshdaskjhd
```

EXPECTED RESULT

```
aasdja
asdasd
```

Comment: `sed` provides a simple way to remove lines matching a pattern using the `d` command. Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5410784/1328439. Is there something specific to js in your case?

Comment: @DimaChubarov That removes all lines that include the PATTERN and not all lines after the pattern is matched

Comment: I think I found a solution:
find . -type f -name '*.js' -exec sed -i "/PATTERN.*/Q" {} \;

Comment: You can answer your own question. Note this only works with GNU sed.

Comment: I disagree with closing this question. Shell programming (and its related commands) is ontopic for stackoverflow (and this question lacks absolutely nothing with regards to "what have you tried", "what is the actual result" and "what is the expected result").

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use `awk`:

```
awk '{a=sub(/PATTERN.*/,"");print ;if(a!=0) exit}'
```

in `sub` function replace `PATTERN` and everything after with nothing. And in `if` check if there was replacement and if yes exit the script